# Where does WebView or WebViewClient make requests to <link>'s

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am loading a html file into a WebView and want to override the WebView's requests to stylesheet **`<link>`** and **`<image>`** elements in the `<head>` so that I can load a file from the machine

the links in the html are like so

```html
<head>
    <link href="../stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 352 500>
        <image width="352" height="500" xlink:href="image.jpeg"/>
   </svg>
</body>
```

I have a WebViewClient with this code but none of these make a request to these links. shouldInterceptRequest and onLoadResource both just recieve the entire html file at `request?.url`

```kotlin
class EpubWebViewClient(): WebViewClient() {
    override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        Log.i("loadurl", "onLoadResource $url")
        super.onLoadResource(view, url)
    }
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
        Log.i("loadurl", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading ${request?.url}")
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
    }
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): WebResourceResponse? {
        Log.i("loadurl", "shouldInterceptRequest ${request?.url}")
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
    }
}
```

I would image there is a function like but perhaps there is not idk

```kotlin
override fun idealUrlOverloadFunction(url: String): String or something else {
   return openLocalFile(url)
}
```

Does the WebView or WebViewClient even make requests for these?

If so how can I interupt them and load a resource from the machine instead of the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by me, consider this link

`<link href="../stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

apending some `string + :' combo such as

`<link href="mystuff:../stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

will cause it to show up in shouldInterceptRequest()

I am unsure as to weather this is caused by the link not firing or shouldInterceptRequest not listening though, but an easy fix with `.replace`